# Are objects returned from a flow immutable?

Tags: salesforce

When I return unsaved objects from a flow, then try to update those objects in a loop, finally saving them. The loop updates are not saved, but the flow object with all its properties are. But if I update the object in the loop, then push the loop object to a variable, then save the variable list, everything is saved fine.

It seems like updates in a loop, with objects from a flow, cannot be updated. Or the object in the loop is just a copy of the original object and not the actual object referenced.

I hope that makes sense.

**This one works**

[image]

**This one does not work**

[image]